# How can I delete a bad chat message for all recipients sent by another user to a Messenger group chat?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-abuse-reporting

I’m a member of a Facebook Messenger chat group that includes my friends.

Someone shared bad videos of me in the chat.

How can I remove or delete the videos?

Answer (score 1):

## Can't Delete Friends' Messages

You can delete the chat messages from your inbox but you can't delete them from your friends'.  See **[Help > Blocking, reporting and deleting](https://facebook.com/help/messenger-app/1145318292241859/)**

If you're concerned about Messenger chat content, you should review Facebook's **standards** as well as some of the **options** available to you.

If the content is a serious violation of the community standards you can report it to Facebook.

## Standards

Content that runs counter to Facebook's community standards includes:

- Bullying or harassment
- Impersonation
- Direct threats
- Sexual violence and exploitation

## Options

If you're concerned about Messenger content, your options include:

1. [Block messages from a profile](https://facebook.com/help/messenger-app/204908296312159/)
2. [Ignore a specific conversation](https://facebook.com/help/messenger-app/1245152242249842/)
3. [Report the message or conversation to Facebook](https://facebook.com/help/messenger-app/833709093422928/)

## Reporting

**[Help > Reporting Conversations](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/1165699260192280)**

> ### Report a Conversation
>
> 1. From [image: Chats icon] Chats, tap a conversation to open it.
> 2. Tap the person's name at the top.
> 3. Scroll down and tap **Report**.
> 4. Select a category to help us understand what's wrong.
> 5. Tap **Submit report**.
>
> ### Report a Message
>
> 1. From your chat, tap and hold the message you want to report.
> 2. Tap **Report**.
> 3. Select a category to help us understand what's wrong.
> 4. Tap **Submit report**.